# Socket not connected in my Android app

Tags: java, android, sockets

I've been working in a server/client application that needs to get the hour from a server working in my computer.

When I try to run this app in my phone it says that SOCKET NOT CONNECTED. I tried everything but it still not working.

The thread is working, but the socket is not connecting!

The permissions I used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The MainActivity.java is:

```
package com.example.clientehora;

/* imports */


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Socket socket = new Socket();
    String SERVER_IP = "10.215.19.41";
    int SERVERPORT = 2000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void ejecutar(View view) {
        try {

            System.out.println("Hola amigo, si me presionaste! =D" + socket.getInetAddress() + socket.getPort());
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String cadena = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("LA CADENA ES: " +cadena);
            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fecha);
            et.setText(cadena);
            br.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }



    class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                 System.out.println("Se ha conectado sin problemas");
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you log success **before** you even make the connection attempt?  In fact you don't appear to be calling your ejecutar() method at all.  When you do call it, you will need to use runOnUiThread for the UI update operations.

Comment: Whatever code you're *actually* running is using the empty non-connected socket you create when the class is instantiated. It's unclear why you're trying to use a thread to create a new socket.

Comment: @BrianRoach - probably because you aren't allowed to do networking operations on the UI thread any more (it was never advisable even when allowed).

Comment: @ChrisStratton Oh no, I fully understand that. However ... this code wouldn't solve that problem simply by instantiating/connecting the socket in a different thread. But you're right ... it's possible the OP doesn't understand that *everything* networky needs to not be on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to connect to my Win7 PC via USB (mTimeout is 5000):

```
mSocket = new Socket();
mSocket.setSoTimeout(mTimeout);
mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT), mTimeout);
```

I get the IP to use using this command on the PC:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```